# Checking many strings in one go in a single (if) statement

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, predicate

I'm trying to check 10 strings not to be empty to run my script. How can I break it down reasonably to stay within one function? My script relies on all of those to be true and it's quite long, so I can't interrogate each one individually. It works with 6 names or less. But from name 7 - 10 I get an error when building my app.

```
if (name[1] != "") && (name2[1] != "") && (name3[1] != "") && (name4[1] != "") && (name5[1] != "") && (name6[1] != "") && (name7[1] != "") && (name8[1] != "") && (name9[1] != "") && (name10[1] != "")
```

I get this error:

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
>   time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Comment: Are `name`, `name1`, `name2` and so on, Array? And you are checking second elements of theme to not be empty. Right?

Comment: Yeah so name would return [“AAAA”, “Proper Name”, “Ident2”]. Or if a wrong code is entered array returns [“”, “”, “”]. Should I extract form array first? Let nameCheck = name[1] then use if nameCheck != “” ?

Comment: Your db function is incorrect, `airportName` will only contain the last row of the second query. Some other thoughts, wouldn't it be better to have only one query with an OR condition instead of two queries and couldn't this check for empty name be part of the db query as well?

Comment: It checks from 2 different entry points to the row. And it works

Comment: If it works it does so in a very inefficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having numbered variable names like that is a big red flag. They should be in an array.

What you're looking for is [`Sequence.allSatisfy(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2996794-allsatisfy), which returns `true` iff all members in a sequence satisfy the provided predicate:

```
let names = [name[1], name1[1], name2[1], ... name10[1]] // this is madness, get rid of these numbered variables

let allNamesArentEmpty = names.allSatisfy { !$0.isEmpty }
if allNamesArentEmpty { ... }
```

Comment: I see so extract my information from 10 arrays in to 1 array containing 10 objects to then check with 1 function?

Comment: @PaulFerga I need more background on your data: What are the 10 `nameN` arrays, anyway? Why is something called a "name" an array?

Comment: You call it `airportName`, yet `airportName[3]` is a latitude, and `airportName[4]` is a longitude. Those aren't names. You need to learn about structs/classes, and define a proper `Airport` struct. Then you can make one `Airport` instance per row in your sqlite db, with a proper `iataCode: String`, `name: String`, `position: CLLocationCoordinate2D`, etc.

Comment: I didn’t have time to code it properly. It all started with airportName, then I added lat and long later to workout distance. And I convert it to position later. It just hasn’t been tidied yet, but it works. I’m working on getting all the functions I need, will tidy it later.

Comment: @PaulFerga That's your call, but you're going to have a bad time dealing with this mess.